# Is Apache Drill Supports high availability

Tags: haproxy, apache-drill

Good Afternoon. I am trying to make Apache drill high availability using Haproxy. I struck with so many doubts.Could you please let me know whether Drill supports High availability using Haproxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using HAproxy

```
frontend apache-drill-ui
         description "Apache Drill UI"
         bind *:8047
         default_backend apache-drill-ui

frontend apache-drill-sql
         description "Apache Drill SQL"
         bind *:31010
         mode tcp
         option tcplog
         default_backend apache-drill-sql

backend apache-drill-ui
        description "Apache Drill UI"
        balance roundrobin
        option httpchk GET /status
        http-check expect string Running
        acl internal_networks src 192.168.0.0/16 172.16.0.0/12 10.0.0.0/8 127.0.0.1
        http-request deny if ! internal_networks
        server ICCCAPANA204 100.65.xx.xx:8047 check
        server ICCCAPANA205 100.65.xx.xx:8047 check 
#      server docker docker:8047 check 
        server 100.65.xxx.xx 100.65.xxx.xx:8047 check
    backend apache-drill-sql

        description "Apache Drill SQL"
        balance roundrobin
        mode tcp
        option tcplog
        acl internal_networks src 192.168.0.0/16 172.16.0.0/12 10.0.0.0/8 127.0.0.1
        tcp-request content reject if ! internal_networks
        option httpchk GET /status
        http-check expect string Running
        server ICCCAPANA204 100.65.xxx.xx:31010 check port 8047
        server ICCCAPANA205 100.65.xxx.xx:31010 check port 8047
#        server docker docker:31010 check port 8047
        server 100.65.212.28 100.65.xxx.xx:31010 check port 8047
```